# How can I perform an aggregation on multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I perform an aggregation on multiple fields? That is I would like to list out the results of a terms aggregation on "field1" and "field2", not separately, but in the same bucket. Is it possible in elasticsearch?

Comment: try using nested aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now there is no direct way to do multi field aggregation in Elasticsearch. But you can achieve the required results using scripts as below:

```
{  
    "aggs": {    
        "mixed_aggs": {      
            "terms": {        
                "script": "doc['field1'].values + doc['field2'].values"      
            }    
        }  
    }
}
```

You can read more about the above case in this [blog](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-scripting-aggregations)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sub-aggregation` as mentioned below:

```
{
"size" : 0,

"aggs": {
  "group_By_field1": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "field1"
     },
     "aggs" : {
       "group_By_Field2" : { 
            "terms": {
        "field": "field2"
     }
       }
     }
   }

 }
}
```

Comment: bur can this be extended to any scenarios?

Comment: What are the scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

This might be accomplished using script as follows :

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "my_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['field_1'].values + doc['field_2'].values"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note : Performance should be considered as combining multiple fields for aggregation comes at a cost.

read [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5100)